# CSS two column layout width (body vs header)

Tags: html, css, width

I'm sure there's a very simple explanation for this but I can't seem to figure it out, would appreciate some help.

Despite all the numbers seeming to add up, and there being essentially no padding or margin anywhere, my main section (consisting of #main and #rightnav) is wider than my header.

What am I missing?

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
body {
background: url('cwbg.jpg');
text-align: center;
border: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
a {
border: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}
img {
vertical-align: top;
}
#container {
width: 800px;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
}
#header {
width: 800px;
height: 100px;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 50px;
}
#main {
width: 650px;
height: 700px;
float: left;
}
#rightnav {
width: 150px;
height: 700px;
float: left;
padding-top: 7px;
}
#rightnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#rightnav img {
float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
    <img src="header.png" alt="Christopher James Wilson">
</div>
<div id="main">
</div>
<div id="rightnav">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_01.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_02.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_03.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_04.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_05.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_06.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_07.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_08.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_09.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_10.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_11.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_12.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_13.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_14.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_15.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="navslices/images/menu_16.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Without seeing a live example, or the actual images, troubleshooting this might be tough.

Comment: What size are the images?  You should specify the width and height attributes of images to aid the browser in rendering them quickly.  Also you may want to use a css reset such as eric meyers css reset or normalize.

Comment: The code is fine. Your images must be pushing thing out as it all lines up here -> http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/xhqFa/

Comment: Not what I see in Chrome. I set a background color to each element and it looks OK. I can tell by the pixels. Can you post a screenshot or more info?

Comment: important information: Browser (do things look the same in IE and Firefox?). Image sizes. Also I don't see `<li>` styling, they may have some extra padding/margin depending on browser (don't think so from your list-style-type, but something you can play with), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Sorry I didn't put a screen cap, I'm not allowed to include images as I'm new, see link to one below. I think it must be something with the images, the CSS stacks up as some of you have shown. I was being lazy by not putting their dimensions and figured I'd go back later but maybe that's it. http://postimage.org/image/piwxwx36t/

Comment: the nav sliced images are probably the culprit, the slicing of each image may not be exactly 150px.

Comment: btw, I am assuming the right navigation is vertically positioned, so there is no need for the `float: left;` in `#rightnav img`

Comment: the float: left in #rightnav img is to get rid of gaps between the images in the ul, only solution I could find

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try relative positioning the elements. If your pictures are wider than the size you set, they may push out the regions.

Another option would be to wrap all the elements in one div.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Sorry I didn't put a screen cap, I'm not allowed to include images as I'm new, see link to one below. I think it must be something with the images, the CSS stacks up as some of you have shown. I was being lazy by not putting their dimensions and figured I'd go back later but maybe that's it. http://postimage.org/image/piwxwx36t/

Comment: update: I've set all the image widths with no change, by inspecting the elements in Chrome I can see that there is space either side of the header image despite being no padding/margin/border

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#container{
width: 800px; /*Width of main container*/
margin: 0 auto; /*Center container on page*/
}

#header{
background: #EAEAEA;
height: 100px; /*Height of top section*/
}

#topsection h1{
margin: 0;
padding-top: 15px;
}

#contentwrapper{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

#rightnav{
margin-left: 650px; /*Set left margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
height:700px;
}

#main{
float: left;
width: 650px; /*Width of left column*/
margin-left: -800px; /*Set left margin to -(MainContainerWidth)*/
background: #C8FC98;
height:700px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>

<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="rightnav">
<b>Content Column:
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  Left Column
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited from DynamicDrive code to suit your request.

For more layouts, please refer to http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/

The problem is as stated above, you lack some position attributes for your div containers.